# SelectFor don't set inital value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentbootstrap

Using FluentBootstrap and trying to figure out how not to have a default selected item.

```
@Html.Bootstrap().SelectFor(x => x.Facility, Model.FacilityList)
    .SetSize(InputSize.Sm)
    .AddAttribute("data-role", "selectize")
```

I'm assuming I need to use SelectFor and not Dropdown since it's coming from a SelectList.

Answer (score 0):

If Model.FacilityList is a SelectList you set the selected value when you create the SelectList.

```
Model.FacilityList = new SelectList(options, "Value", "Key", selectedValue);
```

Comment: Yes doesn't work when pushing it through FluentBootstrap.